# How to load tuned_example in custom script in ray.rllib

Tags: ray

Ray has a number of tuned configurations here: https://github.com/ray-project/ray/tree/master/rllib/tuned_examples. How can I train one of them? (Note I do not want to use rllib/train.py, I want like to use the following self-contained script).

The following is from the examples they provide to train an Ape-X DQN, so I thought of just changing the config they use here with the one provided in https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/rllib/tuned_examples/dqn/atari-dqn.yaml:

```
from ray.rllib.algorithms.apex_dqn.apex_dqn import ApexDQNConfig
config = ApexDQNConfig()
print(config.replay_buffer_config) 
replay_config = config.replay_buffer_config.update( 
    {
        "capacity": 100000,
        "prioritized_replay_alpha": 0.45,
        "prioritized_replay_beta": 0.55,
        "prioritized_replay_eps": 3e-6,
    }
)
config = config.training(replay_buffer_config=replay_config) 
config = config.resources(num_gpus=1)  
config = config.rollouts(num_rollout_workers=30)  
config = config.environment("CartPole-v1")  
algo = config.build() 
algo.train()
```

But I cannot figure out how to change the script, even doing it manually is not trivial as there are these config.function() and I do not know where to put all the elements of the config. Surely there must be an easy way?